# Mosaico email template extension or Mailchimp email integration?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, mosaico, mailchimp

As a small NGO we are about to Upgrade CiviCRM from 4.1.3 to current version 5.9 (as at 18/01/19) and  Migrate CiviCRM from Drupal 6.35 to WordPress CMS.

The two quotes we have offer Mosaico email template extension or Mailchimp email integration. Which woudl work best for an organisation sending out about 10-12 emails a year to 2-3,000 people? What are the pros and  cons of each?

Many thanks 
Margaret

Answer (score 5):

We recommend Mosaico so that all the data stays in CiviCRM. Has it been explained to you that Mosaico works as 'part' of civicrm not as a third party service and hence no 'integration' or 'charges'?

Comment: Thanks that sounds a good reason to go with Mosaico. We have not had integration  or charges mentioned to us.

Comment: You might need to consider how you send your emails. Straight from the server, or using a service like sparkpost, mailgun etc. Since you are already using civicrm you might be able to continue using the same sending method you have been previously using. If you are curious about mosaico - there is a live demo of the base plugin at: https://mosaico.io/. This doesn't show any of the features of the civicrm integration (allowing you to customise emails with firstname lastname etc - but you can get the idea about how it might work in terms of building your content.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on what budget you have for ongoing support and who you are hosting with. Mosaico version 1.x is no longer supported and version 2 and it's various dependencies are all at alpha or beta stage. 
I love mosaico and it's well integrated but it can be complex to setup and maintain. CiviMail can be very demanding, in particular if you're on any kind of shared hosting and most of the development is focused around Drupal at present with Wordpress a bit of a poor cousin. 
 
The mailchimp CiviCRM integration is stable, simple to setup and the templates are compatible with Mosaico if you decide to switch once it's a bit more stable.